# Google cloud: How to check project member's work in /home/<name>/ folder?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have created a project in Google Cloud and gave permissions for App Engine,  Cloud SQL etc to a gmail ID. The user has developed some code in that project. How can I view the code he deployed in that App Engine app?

Comment: I am not sure why its down voted, i am in need of answer for this context

Comment: The path you say would be for local development. Unless your user is developing in a VM, or if the user deployes the code, you will not be able to see their code in their local machine. It does not make sense to be able to access their local files only because you granted them permissions on GCP, that's probably why the question has been downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to download the code using the `appcfg.py download_app` command as [described here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code), unless the code downloads were permanently prohibited in Cloud Console. The tool should work with all languages in standard environment. To verify that download is enabled:

1. Go to your Cloud Console
2. Switch to the project
3. Navigate to *App Engine > Settings*
4. See the section *Permanently prohibit code downloads*

Under some circumstances, you can also inspect code in Cloud Console.

If a [code repository has been setup](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories) (e.g. for CI/CD), you can access the code by:

1. Go to your Cloud Console
2. Switch to the project
3. Navigate to *Source Repositories*
4. Pick a repository and navigate through the directories

If the GAE app uses Standard environment:

1. Go to your Cloud Console
2. Switch to App Engine
3. Navigate to *Versions*
4. In the `"..."` for Tools there is a Source menu item

That said, you should talk to the person who deployed the code. There are many different ways to build and deploy an application. The deployed source code might also reside in an external git repository. You mentioned Cloud SQL, so there might also be other parts that are required for your app to work.

Comment: Most of your answer is right, but this part:  `If the GAE app uses standard environment:

Go to your Cloud Console
Switch to the project
Navigate to Source Repositories
Pick a repository and navigate through the directories......` Did you mean StackDriver logging? Edit your answer please

Comment: The point is the _Source Repositories_ will only be there if you explicitly set them with your app's code. They're not there by default.

Comment: You can connect an app to a repository for CI/CD deployments. But I forgot to mention Stackdriver Debug where one can browse the deployed code of a version (Logging can also link to it). I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hm, you are right, I think the answer would be improved/clarified if I switch the two thing, because Debug will be available and a repository might be available.

Comment: Instead of _If the GAE app uses standard environment:_, You could write _If you have set a source repository for your app's code_. Because having an app in GOOGLE APP ENGINE standard doesn't give you a repo by default, you have to create it by doing this: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories. Only do this change and you're done!

Comment: Thanks @VictorHerasmePerez for your suggestions. I hope the answer is better now.